# Magento 2 shipping rule product specific

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-tax

Have minimum cart total for free shipping. But want to apply specific product  shipping price to be configured and should add up to total.
Please help.

Comment: do you want to apply shipping price per product from admin ?

Comment: yes . Please suggest